# R terra direction - can I do it in only one direction?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

terra::direction() returns values for every single cell in the raster. I have a raster with ~50% of cells value NA, and the rest with a value. What I want is direction() but only for the NA cells, with the rest of the cells not being calculated.

I only want directions for the NA cells because the raster I have is gargantuan, with a thin border of NA cells around the edge whose direction I would like to know. My massive raster is  42893*52031 = 2231765683 cells, while the NA portion of it is only 500000 cells or so - I thought if I can have direction() ignore the non-NA cells, it might be faster.

here is my example:

```
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, crs="+proj=merc")
values(r) <- (c(rep(1, 49), NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 35)))

b <- (direction(r, degrees=T)

plot(b)
```

Can I do direction() on only the NA cells? (or the inverse) any help and insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would be frankly leery of this approach, but as currently written, `direction` is between non-NA cells on a Spatial Raster, and the approach requires selecting a value not otherwise present in the monster to replace NA values with

```
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, crs="+proj=merc")
values(r) <- (c(rep(1, 49), NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 35)))

x <- subst(r, NA, 11)
x1 <- subst(x, 1, NA) # this could be x <- and avoid three giants on disk
# or x2 <- clamp(x, lower = 11L, upper = 11L, value = FALSE)

direction(x1)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
name        :    lyr.1 
min value   : 0.000000 
max value   : 5.695183
```

Oops, I filled my hard drive... Someone will come along with a better idea.